# Iterating through a pair of DataFrames, modifying one of the two at each iteration and feeding back the results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, iteration

I am trying to reimplement a (rather complex) algorithm from R in Python. The algorithm operates on two dataframes (`short` and `long` for simplicity) which have this basic structure:

```
index chrom chr_arm start end ratio_median size
0     chr1  p       1     100  0.789       100
```

The structures of `short` and `long` are identical, they differ from the range in the `size` column (10K-3M for `short` and > 3M for `long`). They are also not identical in length. The algorithm iteratively compares `short` with `long` in different ways and then performs some calculations which **alter `long` in-place**, so that at every iteration the calculations are made with an updated `long`.

EDIT: Someone requested a more detailed description, and I will provide one. This approach needs to merge part the data from `short` into `long` basing on whether they are above or below a certain threshold (defined as `threshold`).

There is also an additional data frame called `bins`, which are the raw data from where `short` and `long` were derived, with this structrure:

```
chrom chr_arm start end ratio ratio_median size
1     p       1     5   0.3   0.7          5
1     p       1     5   0.9   0.7          5
```

The algorithm is as follows:

```
1. Iterate through the lines (indices) of short
2. For each line in short, iterate through the lines of long
3. For each line of long, do a comparison on coordinates between short and long: if short is fully upstream (short end < long start) of long, the check is successful
4. If the check is successful:
   I. measure if the absolute value of the difference between short's ratio_median and the one in long
   II. if the difference is below threshold:
       a. construct a new line (segment) by using the start from short   and the end of long
       b. Measure overlaps between the new line and bins, and recalculate a new ratio_median by doing a median of the overlapping ratios from bins
       c. Replace the current line in long with a new line containing these data
   III. If the difference is above threshold:
       a. Append the current line from short immediately after the current one of long
6. Continue until all lines of short have been used
```

This works more or less in R, but at least in Pandas, modifying DataFrames in-place during iteration is not a good practice (and for good reason). I don't want to replicate the exact way it is done in R (in reality, it's a 600-line `while` loop with multiple nested `if`s) so I tried to make something simpler and more Pythonic.

My first implementation did the logic without updating the DataFrame in place:

```
def adjust_segments(short: pd.DataFrame, long: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    dest_long = long.copy()
    for gid, group in short.groupby(["chrom", "chr_arm"], sort=False):  # To reduce the number of loops
        for rowid, row in group.iterrows():
            for long_id, long_row in long.iterrows():
                if (row.end < long_row.start):  # Simplified check here, there are several
                    if abs(row.ratio_median - long_row.ratio_median) < threshold:
                        new_line = recompute_ratio(row, long_row, bins) 
                        dest_long.loc[long_id, :] = new_line
                    else:
                         # Omitted all checks to see if it's at the end, etc.
                        dest_long.loc[long_id + 1, :] = new_line
```

This "works", but it doesn't feed back the changes on every iteration (it was made like this on purpose before I noticed that the R code - I didn't write it - did things differently).

As I have a numerical `index` column outside the DataFrame index I thought of using that to modify the DataFrame in-place without iterating, but as rows are appended (if checks are not successful) this wouldn't work well with "feeding back" the changes at every iteration.

What approach could be done in a case like this? I really don't want to copy the R approach, as I said, as it would lead to an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Repeatedly update a `list`? Instead of a `DataFrame`? (Or perhaps use `index` as the key of a `dict`.)

Comment: It looks like you want to perform some kind of merge. Difficult to comment without the exact logic.

Comment: @mozway I updated the post with more details on what I need to do.